# Query Matching list is not displaying

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I am new to flutter and I am facing an issue in flutter Autocomplete. I had call an api on textChanged with user's input. Api integration is working fine but I am not getting a list of the matching words in the completer. Here is my code
Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_listview/autocompleter.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'IronWorks',

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (_) =>  new AutoCompleteDemo(), // Login Page
//            '/' :   RepositoryProvider(
//                  builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
//                  child: LoginScreen(),
//          ),

      },
    );
  }
}
```

autocompleter.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'user.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:autocomplete_textfield/autocomplete_textfield.dart';

class AutoCompleteDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  AutoCompleteDemo() : super();

  final String title = "AutoComplete Demo";

  @override
  _AutoCompleteDemoState createState() => _AutoCompleteDemoState();
}

class _AutoCompleteDemoState extends State<AutoCompleteDemo> {
  AutoCompleteTextField searchTextField;
  GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<User>> key = new GlobalKey();
  static List<User> users = new List<User>();
  bool loading = true;
  String name ="";

  void getUsers(name) async {
    try {
      final response =
      await http.get("https://pptndt.com/api/unitsDropDown?name="+name);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        users = loadUsers(response.body);
        print('Users: ${users.length}');
//        print(users);
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      } else {
        print("Error getting users.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error getting users.");
    }
  }

  static List<User> loadUsers(String jsonString) {
    final parsed = json.decode(jsonString).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
//    getUsers(name);
    super.initState();
  }

//  Widget row(User user) {
//    return Row(
//      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
//      children: <Widget>[
//        Text(
//          user.name,
//          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
//        ),
//        SizedBox(
//          width: 10.0,
//        ),
//      ],
//    );
//  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
//          loading
//              ? CircularProgressIndicator():
               searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField<User>(
            key: key,
            clearOnSubmit: false,
            suggestions: users,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0),
              hintText: "Search Name",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),

                 textChanged: (query) => getUsers(query),
            itemFilter: (item, query) {
              print(item);
              return item.name
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
            },

            itemSorter: (a, b) {
              return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
            },

            itemSubmitted: (item) {
              setState(() {
                searchTextField.textField.controller.text = item.name;
              });
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, item) {
              // ui for the autocompelete row
//              print(row);
//              print(context);
//              return row(item);
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    item.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

user.dart

```
class User {
//  int id;
  String name;
//  String email;

  User({this.name});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return User(
//      id: parsedJson["id"],
      name: parsedJson["name"] as String,
//      email: parsedJson["email"] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you print the catch error:

```
... 
   } catch (e) { 
     print(e); 
   }
```

It show:

```
XMLHttpRequest error.
```

I think it can be CORS from server, try to put this in your php header:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: This is not my issue. Api is working fine but I am not getting the list in the completer

Comment: You dont get nothing because it don't pas the XMLHttpRequest error. I tried your code in my computer and that was the result. The Api don't accept calls from outside, but if the call comes from it's scope it works ok.